# Where does the VS2012 Publishing Wizard get its file references?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, deployment, web-deployment

I am having an issue where when I select to publish my MVC project to the file system so I may upload it later via FTP to my Web Host, it fails complaining of missing files.

Believing that it may think these files are required to compile the project, I copy them to the locations that it expects and it resolves the error but produces yet another error about another missing file.

These files incidentally are not required to run my Web Application but were simply files used during the initial test phase of my project. More specifically, picture files.

The next step I took to resolve the issue was to Clean and rebuild the Solution and Project Entirely with all those files it was referencing in the errors removed. The Project builds successfully and runs as expected.

I then attempt to publish to the file system and again it complains of those files as if its getting that information from somewhere other than obvious places within my Project.

I have deleted the object directory content, cleaned and rebuilt; again it references these files that don't exist anywhere within my Solution.

So my question is, Where exactly does the Web Publishing Wizard get the information it uses to copy the required files to the Target Location? I've checked the .pubxml file but there's nothing in there that would provide the information.

For instance, if I'd initially built my site using reference to a .png file then later use a .jpg file. The Wizard seems to be getting the metadata for the initial build somewhere and insists on inclusion of the .png file when it is no longer needed.

I believe I have Upgraded to the latest build and patches for VS2012. I am Currently running version 11.0.50727.1 and using .NET 4.5

I cannot find any relevant information on this problem so it may be a quirk in my Environment so I'm searching for some feedback.

If no answer can be provided, if I could simply know what folders and files are required to deploy an MVC site; I'll perform the deploy manually and trash the Wizard concept. I just thought it would be the most appropriate way to deploy but if its going to be a pain; I don't need it.

This is the Error:

```
Error : Copying file <relative path>\image.png to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\<relative path>\image.png failed. 

Could not find file '<relative path>\image.png'.
```

The new file that replaced the old file is actually image.jpg and its in there. I could alleviate this error by copying the old file back to its initial location, but why should I if its no longer required?